# How to enable the usage of fork(), wait() and execv()

Tags: c, codeblocks

I have an assignment to do which requires me to use fork(), wait and execv(). However, every time I try to use them I get an error that they aren't defined. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

    fork();

    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the errors I get:

[image]

I would appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: looks like windows, unistd.h doesnt exist on windows, nor does fork

Comment: @pm100 What does that means? What can I do?

Comment: Get access to a linux machine and do you work there. That means use someone else's machine or install a [hypervisor](https://www.hitechnectar.com/blogs/open-source-hypervisor/) and then create or download a linux vm that the hypervisor can run.

Comment: I already have a linux machine but I don't get it what does this have to do with it? like I saw videos where fork and wait work in visual studio regularly.

Comment: Microsoft explains the options you have [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/y23kc048(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN0.).

Comment: you can install WSL - windows subsystem for Linux, it works greate, you get ubuntu running on you windows box, takes 15 minutes to setup

Comment: Can you show us one of those videos please, post a link here - I am curious

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cex9XrZCU14&t

Comment: Thats visual studio code running on linux. It runs on windows mac and linux. Its not a windows specific IDE. see https://code.visualstudio.com/ (whoever chose that name made a huge mistake IMHO)

Comment: It worked after I tried using it with linux virtual machine, Thanks.

Comment: WSL doesn't have to be Ubuntu, by the way.  There are several options, and I, for one, use SUSE.

Comment: @mohamadS. Did my answer solve your doubts?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using a Windows machine and Windows does not support the fork-exec model, as it does not have a system call analogous to fork().

You have multiple solutions:

- use a Linux SO
- use the WSL on Windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install
- use command-line interface that simulates Linux environments on Windows, like Cygwin http://www.cygwin.com/. In this case, the tool simulates how Linux processes works so is particularly slow but for an execise is ok.